# Hartshorne endomorphism of degree 2 of an elliptic curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

I have some trouble solving Hartshorne chapter Ex.IV.4.5.

For an elliptic curve $X$, a point $P_0$ of $X$, and a morphism $f:X \rightarrow X$ of degree 2, let $\pi : X \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$ be the morphism defined by the divisor $2P_0$.

(a) states that there exist a morphism $\pi' : X \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$ and $g : \mathbb{P}^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$ both of degree 2 such that $\pi f = g \pi'.$

Here we have $(\pi f)^*\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(1) = (g \pi')^*\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(1)$, so if we let $D$ be the divisor on $X$ corresponding to $\pi'$, we have $2D \sim 2f^*(P_0)$.

If we let $D = f^*(P_0)$, this solves (a). However (observing other solutions), later in (c) I felt that it is supposed to take $D = 2f(P_0)$, but then I cannot solve (a). How does this go?

Comment: This question was recently posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4268734/given-a-degree-two-endomorphism-of-an-elliptic-curve-how-to-construct-the-follo

Comment: What other solution are you talking about? I've seen one out there but the person writing it seems to get things backwards in important ways - like they swap the roles of $\pi$ and $\pi'$, for instance.

Comment: Dear Liu Y, I posted an answer to my question at the link that Viktor left above which should solve your problem. I've verified that my approach leads to the right answer in part (c).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Given a degree-two endomorphism of an elliptic curve, how to construct the following map to $\Bbb P^1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4268734/given-a-degree-two-endomorphism-of-an-elliptic-curve-how-to-construct-the-follo)

Comment: @Hank Scorpio Yes. Thanks.