# When is $l(D)\neq 0$ for $D$ a degree-zero divisor on an elliptic curve?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be a field (algebraically closed if necessary) and let $X$ be an elliptic curve over $k$. Let $D$ be a divisor of degree zero on $X$. How can I tell when $\mathcal{O}_X(D)$ has global sections? When $D$ has positive or negative degree, I understand what's going on: if $D$ has negative degree, then it has no global sections, and when $D$ has positive degree we have $l(D)=\deg D$ by Riemann-Roch. But the case of $\deg D=0$ is unclear to me. I bet it probably depends on the configuration of points, but I don't really know how or why.

Context: I'm working my way through chapter IV of Hartshorne and realized I don't understand this. It originally came up in an attempt to work on [this previous question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4268734/given-a-degree-two-endomorphism-of-an-elliptic-curve-how-to-construct-the-follo) (which I'm still stuck on).

Comment: If $\deg(D) = 0$ then $l(D) > 0$ if and only if $D$ is linearly equivalent to the zero divisor.

Answer (score 3):

If there is a nonzero $f \in L(D)$, then the sum of $D$ and the divisor of $f$ has nonnegative entries and degree $0$, so it must be zero. Thus $D$ is principal (it’s the divisor of $1/f$). The reverse implication is easy.

Comment: Ok, great - how do I check that my configuration of points is linearly equivalent to the zero divisor, though? If I've got $\sum n_iP_i$, do I just go through and do some sort of addition in the group law? Follow-up part two: it seems like I'm not going to get what I wanted out of this - I was trying to use this to check if there was a rational function with poles at certain points and zeroes at other points. What should I look at to do that instead?